# Asciidoctor how to add header and footer in title page and ignore margin

Tags: header, margin, footer, asciidoctor

I'm wondering if someone knows how to make a header and footer at the title page in your costume Asciidoctor theme.

In my case I have a logo that I want to put on the top left corner. The problem is that I've set the margin for the document, so my logo would not be on the right spot at the title page.

Do someone of you know how to ignore the margin or just how to add a header and footer to the title page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using "title_page_logo_image", you should be able to accomplish this through "title_page_background_image". The background image does not take the margins into account. You may have to update the logo to include some transparency to its left and top in order to not make it sit exactly in the top left of the title page.

Marc.